# Let f be a alternating n-linear form on E, then there exists $\lambda\in\Bbb K$ such that f = $\lambda$ det$_e$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\Bbb K$ be a field ( $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ ) , $E$ be a non-empty $\Bbb K$-vector space of finite dimension $n$. Let $f$ be a alternating $n$-linear form on $E$.
Proof there exists $\lambda\in\Bbb K$ such that $f = \lambda \cdot det_e$.
Proof the map det$_e$ is the unique alternating $n$-linear form on $E$ which equal to 1$_\Bbb K$ at $e=(e_1,e_2, ... , e_n)$.
The following are definitions or theorems that have already been proven that I'm not sure if we'll need:

1. $S_n$ is symmetric group with degree n. $sgn(\sigma)$ is the sign of $\sigma$
   Note that  det$_e$ is the determinant respect the basis $e$, which map from $E^n$ into $\Bbb K$ and defined by the following way
   $det_e(x_1,x_2, ... , x_n)$ = $\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} sgn(\sigma)\Pi_{i=1}^n x_{\sigma(i),i}$
   where $\forall j \in [1,n], j\in \Bbb N$, $x_j = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i,j}e_i$.
2. $\forall \sigma \in S_n, f(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}, ... , x_{\sigma(n)}) = \text{sgn}(\sigma)f(x_1,x_2, ... ,x_n)$

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the multilinearity of $f$. Can you see that

$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{j_1,\ldots,j_n=1}^n \left(\prod_{k=1}^n x_{k, j_k}\right)f(e_{j_1}, \ldots, e_{j_n})?$$

Now what happens if two of $j_k$ are the same? What happens if they are all distinct? Can you finish the proof?

Comment: emm... no. Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know. This wasn't what I voted; when I replied, it was already -1.

Comment: So what did you not understand in the formula that I wrote?

Comment: I understand. But I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Try to se what happens if $n=2$